# 1 (key)s remain to be installed

Tags: hadoop, ssh, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

While making ssh without asking password. I tried the following

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.200.4
```

It shows me the following error:

[image: snapshot]

Answer (score 2):

Try running "ssh-add" on your client PC. It should solve the problem.

Basically the reason why it works is (quoted from [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)):

> `ssh-add` adds RSA or DSA identities to the authentication agent, `ssh-agent(1)`. When run without arguments, it adds the files `~/.ssh/id_rsa`, `~/.ssh/id_dsa` and `~/.ssh/identity`.

Comment: Yes, but *why* would this solve the problem? Remember, you're not only answering for the poster, but also readers in the future.

Comment: ssh-add adds RSA or DSA identities to the authentication agent, ssh-agent(1). When run without arguments, it adds the files ~/.ssh/id_rsa, ~/.ssh/id_dsa and ~/.ssh/identity.  (from http://linux.die.net/man/1/ssh-add)

Comment: You should [edit] your answer, and include that information.

Answer (score 0):

> It shows me the following error:

There is no error. It says it copied your key to the server.